# React | ForwardedRef using React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm creating a custom component in React, and I need to export it using forwardedRef. But when I try, this error occurs:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyP5G.png)

`my code:`

```
export interface ButtonProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>{
  ref?: React.RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>;
}

class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps> {

  render() {
    const {
      ref,
      children,
      ...otherProps
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <button 
        {...otherProps} 
        ref={ref}
      >
        {children}
      </button>
    )
  }
}

const ButtonForwarded = React.forwardRef<ButtonProps>((props, ref) => 
<Button {...props} ref={ref} /> );

ButtonForwarded.displayName = 'Button';

export default ButtonForwarded;
```

Comment: Try to rename the ref property to some other name in the Button component.

Answer (score 2):

Create the **ButtonForwarded** component like this:

```
const ButtonForwarded = React.forwardRef((props: ButtonProps, ref: LegacyRef<Button>) => <Button {...props} ref={ref} /> );
```